# Sending Notification To One App In A Project With Multiple Apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

A little late night pressure trying to release an app and I realized how different Firebase was from original GCM. I have searched everywhere and I can't find an answer to my situation. I have two apps in my Firebase project and I want to only send notifications to 1 app and not the other. I am currently using AWS as the push notification provider. It is asking me like usual api key and sender id but I noticed that both api key and sender Id in the cloud messaging section of firebase is the same for both apps in the project. I am missing some step inside of firebase to assign different values so I can use AWS or do I have to use firebase for push notifications to achieve what I want.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Doug. You don't specifically have to implement in an app if you don't have to. Having two apps in the same project, for FCM, would result in having the same credentials. However, there is also the option of creating a different Server Key now (also in the Cloud Messaging Tab). I'm not too familiar with AWS, but if it's looking for a credential, you'll have to provide the same. That or you'd want to create a separate project for the other app.